# IIS, incomplete data transmission, and status code 400

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-post

I've noticed that my ASP.Net aspx page (running on IIS7.5) sometimes receives http POST requests where the content-length in the header is not the same as the Request.InputStream.Length.

Sometimes the actual length is 0, other times > 0, but for these requests, definitely != purported length in the http header.   (The clients of this page are using http 1.0, so it's not related to 100 continue status.  They are not browsers.).

I had thought that such a malformed request would never get as far as being processed by my asp.net page - that IIS would return a 400 (or something similar) at a lower level.

Does this situation sound correct to you, and if so, is there a switch you can toggle to make this check globally in asp.net so my page does not try to process incomplete data, or does it have to be done manually in code?

If relevant, the clients are submitting data with ContentType = "application/text", Keep-Alive = false.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I've got a similar problem with "text/JSON" content, except the actual length is always above 0 but too often does not match the expected length.

Comment: Our hosting provider looked into it for us and it was something to do with packet fragmentation. They tweaked some stuff in the data centre and it seems to be working OK for us now.